# Need to display first four letters of date (freemarker)

Tags: freemarker

The copy editors at my job are very specific on how they want the date displayed. The code I use now works perfectly for months abbreviated by three letters. Doesn't work for Sept.

Current code:

```
${(.now?long - 259200000)?number_to_date?string['MMM. d']}
```

Is there a way to display the date as Sept xx ?